# Nested case statement - what's is wrong with it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a nested case statement where i want in Microsoft SQL Server that

```
case 
    when date 2 is null 
        then date 1 
        else date 2 
end ---1st condition
```

and use this condition as:

```sql
case 
    when condition1 is <= getdate() 
         and condition1 < getdate() + 14 
        then 'DUE' 
        else 'after .
```

I am getting error message and not able to complete my case statement.

Comment: Your "1st condition" can just be expressed as `ISNULL(Date2, Date1)` - then use that in your `CASE`

Comment: *" am getting error message"* And what is that error? Also that is a `CASE` **expression**, not a `Case` statement.

Comment: `and condition1 < getdate() + 14` is irrelevent, as it will always be true if the first line is true

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the 1st check because both the checks are comparing getdate

```
case when isnull([date 1],[date 2]) <= getdate() + 14 then 'DUE' else <'' end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use CROSS APPLY for this :

```
SELECT t2.y
FROM sometable
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN date 2 IS NULL THEN date 1 ELSE date 2 END) t1(x)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN t1.x <= getdate() AND t1.x < getdate() + 14 THEN 'DUE' ELSE 'AFTER' END) t2(y)
```

Note that you can use COALESCE to make the first CROSS APPLY expression simpler, and IIF for the second :

```
SELECT t2.y
FROM sometable
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COALESCE(date 2, date 1)) t1(x)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT IIF(t1.x <= getdate() AND t1.x < getdate() + 14, 'DUE', 'AFTER')) t2(y)
```